# Format 1999 as 19.99 in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to format `1999` into `19.99` using PHP number format.

I tried:

`$<?php echo number_format('1999',2); ?>`

But I received:

`$1,999.00` instead of `$19.99`

Please help!

Comment: Err, divide by 100 perhaps? PHP is only using the number you're supplying

Answer (score 2):

Simply divide the number by 100

`$<?php echo number_format(1999/100,2); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

```
$<?php 
$value = 1999;
echo number_format(($value/100),2); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
echo number_format((1999/100),2);
```